# What is the difference between these two JSFiddle's?

Tags: dojo, jsfiddle

I cannot find a difference in code or settings but one does what I want and the other does not.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lr5c8vtb/2/

HTML

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="label: 'gugu'">My Button</button>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="dbox1" checked
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox">
<label for="dbox1">Want</label>
```

Javascript

```
require(["dojo/parser"], function(parser) {

});
```

vs

https://jsfiddle.net/2mnm8py2/1/

HTML

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="label: 'gugu'">My Button</button>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="dbox1" checked
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox">
<label for="dbox1">Want</label>
```

Javascript

```
require(["dojo/parser"], function(parser) {

});
```

Comment: Ha! Is this some sick joke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external resources the jsFiddle is loading are different.

Open up your browser console and it will tell you whats wrong

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   https://fiddle.jshell.net/Lr5c8vtb/2/show/claro.css"
>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   https://fiddle.jshell.net/Lr5c8vtb/2/show/dojo.css"

The working fiddle is referencing Google's hosted version of the files

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css

Answer (score 4):

The external references (CSS files) are not being properly referenced in the first link.

Refrences should be:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css